# Vue SSR lose url #hash when redirect

Tags: node.js, vue.js, server-side-rendering

Aplication on Vue.js with SSR. 
For example I have page with url anchors like this http://localhost/faq#question5

But when I run SSR it lose hash part of url.

From docs:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const { app, router } = createApp()

    // I lose my hash in this place, because I don't have url with hash on server side
    router.push(context.url)
    .....
}
```

Docs here:
https://ssr.vuejs.org/guide/routing.html#routing-with-vue-router

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fragments (hashes) are stripped from the URL when send to the server. Maybe you can convert the values to parameters? See more here. https://blog.httpwatch.com/2011/03/01/6-things-you-should-know-about-fragment-urls/